# How to install bulma-tagsinput extension in Angular project?

Tags: angular, bulma

I am trying to install [bulma-tagsinput](https://wikiki.github.io/form/tagsinput/) in my Angular project without success.

Below the steps I did:

1. Install the package with `npm i bulma-tagsinput`
2. Declare `bulma-tagsinput.min.js` in my `angular.json`

```
"scripts": ["./node_modules/bulma-tagsinput/dist/js/bulma-tagsinput.min.js"]
```

3. In my `main.ts`, import the extension and run the attach command

```
import * as bulmaTagsinput from 'bulma-tagsinput';

bulmaTagsinput.attach();
```

4. Add the extension in my sass file after bulma

```
@import "~bulma";

@import '~bulma-tagsinput/dist/css/bulma-tagsinput';
```

5. See the result in text and not in tags
   [image: result]

Is there something else to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to add the extension to my project.

The import of the extension and the attach command declaration have to be made in the component where the bulmaTagsinput is used. (not in the main.ts)

For instance:

- foo.component.ts

  ```
  import * as bulmaTagsinput from 'bulma-tagsinput';

  ngOnInit() {

    /* some code */

    bulmaTagsinput.attach();
  }
  ```
- foo.component.html

  ```
  <input class="input" type="tags" placeholder="Add Tag" value="Tag1,Tag2,Tag3">
  ```

**BUT**

I was not able to get the values of the input after binding it with a form control element. My values were always undefined so I guess bulma-tagsinput is not made to work with Angular...

Answer (score 0):

The described Module bulma-tagsinput is not made to work with Angular.

The main.ts file ist the script-loader of Angular and starts the Module bulma-tagsinput immediately after Angular starts. But Angular have not rendered any Element into the DOM. So better use a Tags-Input-Implementation for Angular.

For Example use Angular Material, it includes Components and Directives to build tags-input-elements. They call it Chips:

https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview